# Losing SSH access to Acquia Cloud: "permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

Sometimes, when working on an Acquia Cloud project, I seemingly spontaneously lose git access on the AC server. This might be related to switching between multiple workstations while working on the project. When I try to run a git command, I get

`Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

I have not changed my keys related to this project.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't determined the root cause of this issue, but I found a functional solution:

When I get this issue, rather than in my IDE I ssh to AC via the Acquia Dev Desktop interface (clicking the small terminal icon next to the SSH address). This runs a specific SSH connection with several options:

`ssh -p 22 -i "/Users/username/.ssh/acquia_key_name" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null sitename.dev@server.devcloud.hosting.acquia.com`

After this command is run (in my case in Mac Terminal), I can access the git repo again via my IDE.

Comment: This solutions works!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with connecting to Acquia Cloud within my vagrant box. After reading the above solution I managed to get the connection to work by running the following from my home directory:

```
ssh -p 22 -i ".ssh/acquia_key_name" sitename.dev@server.devcloud.hosting.acquia.com
```

Then I ssh-ed back into my vagrant box and managed to connect